# Printing remote pdf in Sencha ExtJs from Spring-Boot app doesn´t work

Tags: spring, pdf, extjs

I have an ExtJS app that shows a PDF from a spring boot app using a REST service. So far this works fine but when I have updated the spring-boot version from 1.3 -> 1.4, the code doesn´t work fine and shows me a blank PDF as response.

This is my code:

ExtJS - Sencha

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: MyApp.Application.Globals.baseUrl + url,
    params: params,
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    headers:{
        'Authorization': Utils.getAuthorization()
    },
    scope : this,
    // ON SUCCESS
    success: function(response) {
        window.open('data:application/pdf,' + escape(response.responseText));
    },
    // ON FAILURE
    failure: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Server Code (Spring-Boot)

```
String report = reportService.executeReport(....);

response.setContentType("application/pdf");

try {
    response.getWriter().write(report);
} catch (IOException e) {
    ELogger.error(this, CoreConstants.LOGGER_CATEGORY, "error creating pdf", e);
}
```

POM

```
<spring-boot.version>1.4.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version> with 1.3.3 it works fine
```

If anyone can help me, I will be grateful.

Regards!

Comment: Finally i have found the workaroung, i have modify the respone object, now i have a

Answer (score 0):

I have found the workaround using ResponseEntity as a response:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example", produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> exampleMethod(){

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "filename=sysparamspdf");
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");

    headers.setContentLength(report.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length);
    ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> response = new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(
            new InputStreamResource(stream), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
```

}